# Yellow Text in Solidworks, Can't Change

Tags: text, drawing, ordinal, solidworks

I'm working on a SolidWorks mechanical drawing generated from a 3-D model I created. I added ordinals to the drawing and text for the sheet title, but all of my text is coming out in yellow:

[image: yellow text]

I've checked that the layer is set to 0, and that the color for layer 0 is set to black. I've also gone through the Options-->System Options-->Colors screen but it did not help me figure out why everything is yellow. It must be a local setting somewhere, because when I try opening the files on another computer it works fine. It's just a pain right now, though, because I need to export to PDF and it shows up as yellow in the PDF instead of black. Is there a setting somewhere that I may have missed?

Comment: Anybody have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I would personally go to the settings to determine what type of dimensions SolidWorks assigns the yellow color to.

```
Tools Options -> Colors -> Color Scheme
```

By doing that, you will able to figure out what's wrong with the dimension.

Generally speaking, yellow is assigned to dangling dimensions (Dimensions of parts they were modified or deleted).

Comment: Thanks. I had already done that and even changed everything that was set to yellow to a different color, and it still showed up as yellow. I ended up calling customer support and it turned out it was a registry problem